# symfony2 : form errors not displayed in twig despite a non null getErrorsAsString()

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, twig

I am using symfony 2 and I have a form on which I put @Assert\NotBlank() annotations.
I am volontarily filling the fields, my form does not pass the isValid and isSubmitted test and after those lines I get a non-null value for exit(var_dump($recipeForm->getErrors()));

```
  private 'errors' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)[4119]
          private 'message' => string 'Cette valeur doit Ãªtre vide.' (length=29)
          protected 'messageTemplate' => string 'This value should be blank.' (length=27)
          protected 'messageParameters' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'messagePluralization' => null
          private 'cause' => 
            object(Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation)[4062]
              ...
          private 'origin' => null
```

In my twig template I render the form with a simple form(form). form_errors(form) or form_errors(form.field) won't render the errors. Why? Why could I do to further understand where the issue comes from?

I have a pretty complicated type. for some other forms of my website, the errors are correctly displayed.
My type:

```
<?php
//src/AppBundle/Form/FoodAnalytics/RecipeType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\FoodAnalytics;

use AppBundle\Form\Core\MediaType;
use AppBundle\Repository\FoodAnalytics\UnitRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RecipeType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $recipeIngredientQueryBuilder;
    protected $recipeSubrecipeQueryBuilder;
    protected $unitRepository;
    protected $action;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_foodanalytics_recipe' . $this->action;
    }

    public function __construct(UnitRepository $unitRepository, $recipeIngredientQueryBuilder=null, $recipeSubrecipeQueryBuilder=null, $action = null)
    {
        $this->recipeIngredientQueryBuilder = $recipeIngredientQueryBuilder;
        $this->recipeSubrecipeQueryBuilder = $recipeSubrecipeQueryBuilder;
        $this->unitRepository = $unitRepository;
        $this->action = $action == null ? null : '_' . $action;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('recipeCategories', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity',array(
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\RecipeCategory',
                    'label' => 'Catégories',
                    'required' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'title'=>"Indiquez les catégories dans lesquelles enregistrer la recette pour un recherche future plus facile",
                    )))
            ->add('isProduct', null, array(
                    'label'=>'Correspond à un produit fini',
                    'required'=>false,
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'title'=>"La recette correspond-elle à un produit fini qui peut être mis en vente ?",
                    )))
            ->add('name', null, array(
                    'label'=>'Nom détaillé',
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'title'=>"Indiquez le nom détaillé de la recette. Par exemple : 'millefeuilles praliné ganache vanille sur feuilletage inversé'",
                    )))
            ->add('nickName', null, array(
                    'label'=>'Nom raccourci',
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'title'=>"Indiquez un nom raccourci pour la recette. Par exemple : 'millefeuilles'",
                    )))
            ->add('recipeIngredients', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new RecipeIngredientType($this->unitRepository, $this->recipeIngredientQueryBuilder),
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'label'=>'Ingrédient',
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'cascade_validation' => true,
                ))
            ->add('subrecipes', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new RecipeSubrecipeType($this->unitRepository, $this->recipeSubrecipeQueryBuilder),
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'label'=>'Sous-recette',
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true
                ))
            ->add('recipeSteps', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new RecipeStepType(),
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'label'=>'Etape de production',
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true
                ))
            ->add('portions', null, array(
                    'label'=>'Nombre de parts / de pièces',
                    'required' => false,
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'title'=>"Indiquez le nombre d'éléments disponibles dans la recette. Cela peut permettre d'utiliser l'unité 'U' dans les recettes parentes qui l'utiliseront",
                    )))
            ->add('shortDescription', null, array(
                    'label'=>'Description courte',
                    'required'=>false,
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'title'=>"Décrivez succinctement la recette",
                    )))
            ->add('medias', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new MediaType(),
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'label'=>'Medias',
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'attr'=>array(
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'title'=>"Ajoutez des images ou vidéos pour décrire la recette",
                    )))
            ->add('content', 'textarea', array(
                    'label'=>'Instructions générales',
                    'required'=>false,
                    'attr' => array(
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'class' => 'summernote',
                        'title'=>"Ajoutez du contenu supplémentaire pour détailler la recette",
                    )))
            ->add('workingDuration', 'timepicker', array(
                        'label'=>'Temps total de travail',
                        'required' => false,
                        'attr'=>array
                        (
                            'class' => 'timepicker',
                            'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                            'data-placement'=>"top",
                            'title'=>"Indiquez le temps total de travail consacré à la recette si il diffère du temps de travail cumulé des étapes de production",
                        )))
            ->add('sleepDuration', 'timepicker', array(
                    'label'=>'Temps total de repos',
                    'required' => false,
                    'attr'=>array
                    (
                        'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                        'class'=>'timepicker',
                        'data-placement'=>"top",
                        'title'=>"Indiquez le temps total de repos consacré à la recette si il diffère du temps de repos cumulé des étapes de production",
                    )))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\FoodAnalytics\Recipe',
//            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

EDIT: keeping only one simple field of this form does not change anything, the error won't get shown

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at how errors are rendered here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#customizing-error-output

The problem with using `{{ form_errors(form) }}` is that it displays global form errors, not individual fields, whereas `getErrorsAsString()` will drill-down through all of the fields.  If you want all of the individual field errors to be accessible via `{{ form_errors(form) }}`, then you need to edit every single field in your form and add the option `error_bubbling => true`.

If you don't set the error bubbling to true on all of our fields, then you will need to render each field's error individually - for example: `{{ form_errors(form.name) }}`, or just using `{{ form_row(form.name) }}` which renders the label, form element, and errors all in one shot.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error_bubbling => true does not work. If i am rendering the form with form(form) or form_errors(form.field) or form_row(form.field), nothing changes. I have also an empty dump for those values whereas the getErrorsAsString is not empty. Some other forms on my site are just working fine... Do you know how to follow the errors from where they're caught to where they're displayed? I think I need additionnal debugging tricks...

Comment: Did you make sure to put `error_bubbling => true` on each individual field?  When I first started with Symfony forms I thought I could set that option for the entire form, but that's not the case.  It has to be per field.  Perhaps you could post the configuration where you added error bubbling, as well as your Twig code for displaying the form?

Comment: well, if I put error_bubbling on nickName and also put an Assert\NotBlank(), I just get the same: no errors show but I can see the error in the getErrorsAsString. I'll put a simpler form error example to try to narrow it down

Answer (score 3):

Ah my god!

I'm sorry i made people lose time with this! The issue was I was passing as a response an array `$response = array(form->createView())` but this array response was generated before I handle the request. Hence why I could see it in the vardump and not in twig.

Comment: It's almost always something simple.  Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the error is caused by a validation rule on a property that is part of your `Recipe` entity but not added to `RecipeType` so the error is unable to be linked to any sub-forms.

Try to check your entity and find which property has validation rule and not added to the `RecipeType` either add a default value for that property or use `Validation Groups`

Comment: well, the error is actually caused by a field added to recipetype, and I know which one as I volontarily field it wrong. The form->geterrorsasstring displays the right error but not the twig template, this is the strange part.